# Swagger2.0 if Parent is specified then all its children should be mandatory

Tags: swagger-2.0

I am using Swagger2.0 to define my API. One of the requirements is that:

- I have a field MyParent that is Optional
- its children instead are all mandatory whenever MyParent is specified

  - MyParent_child1 mandatory if MyParent is specified
  - MyParent_child2 mandatory if MyParent is specified

How can I model this behaviour in my Swagger definition?

Comment: Just to clarify - are "MyParent" and "MyParent_child1/child2" SIBLING properties (on the same nesting level), or are "MyParent_child1/child2" INSIDE "MyParent"?

Comment: They are inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `MyParent` an an optional property, and its child properties `MyParent_child1` and `MyParent_child2` as required. When `MyParent` is omitted, its child properties are omitted too, so child property validations do not apply in this case.

```yaml
MyModel:
  type: object
  required:
    - foo
  properties:
    foo:
      type: string
    ...
    MyParent:  # not required
      type: object
      properties:
        MyParent_child1:
          type: string
        MyParent_child2:
          type: string
      required:
        - MyParent_child1
        - MyParent_child2
```